# NestJs Swagger: Cannot find module - (external type not found)

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I have an entity like this where I define a `timestamp` field that is a `luxon` `DateTime`:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import { Table, Column, Model, DataType } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'

@Table({})
export default class MyModel extends Model<MyModel> {
  @ApiProperty({type: () => DateTime})
  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
  })
  timestamp: DateTime
}
```

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

When I try to start my `NestJs` server, the swagger plugin tries to get types from my entity meta-data, which causes it to try and `require` the `'../../../node_modules/@types/luxon/index'` `luxon` types.

The types are installed, and I can see them. They also seem to be recognized by my vscode.

However, I get the error:

```
(node:272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../../../node_modules/@types/luxon/index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.type (projectDir\dist\src\usage\entities\register-read.entity.js:24:158)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:86:38)
    at modelProperties.map.key (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:55:35)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.exploreModelSchema (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:54:52)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.createNotBuiltInTypeReference (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:117:37)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:93:25)
    at modelProperties.map.key (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:55:35)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.exploreModelSchema (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:54:52)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.createNotBuiltInTypeReference (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:117:37)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:93:25)
    at modelProperties.map.key (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:55:35)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.exploreModelSchema (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:54:52)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.createNotBuiltInTypeReference (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:117:37)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (projectDir\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\services\schema-object-factory.js:93:25)
```

Comment: Im having the same problem. Did you ever find an anwser??

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be caused by broken code in swagger/versions > 4.09

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by a `.ts` file outside `src/` dir. I store NodeJS scripts in `/scripts` dir, at the same level as `src/`, and somehow that affects `@netsjs/swagger`. Renaming scripts to `.js` solved the issue.